I would like to display a table from a panda data frame
I am looking for a solution to display a table in a window (separate from the console). I am using Ubuntu 22.04 system.
The data are processed by pandas.
I found this guide: https://www.delftstack.com/fr/howto/python-pandas/pandas-display-dataframe-in-a-table-style/
that the Styler object may display a table from a DataFrame.
Thus, I tried this:
Inside the code, there is a 2D list called "week". I would like to display it:
df = pd.DataFrame(week)

df.style

print(df)

But, nothing new happens after doing df.style. However, print(df) works fine.

Have you tried using a Jupyter notebook? It's useful for separate charts visualizations, so you could display your pd.DataFrame() in different cells, I'm assuming that is what you mean by display a dataframe in separate windows.

Thanks for pointing this out, Hopefully OP looked at the styler intro guide in the Pandas Visulization documentation and read, "The DataFrame.style attribute is a property that returns a Styler object. It has a _repr_html_ method defined on it so it is rendered automatically in Jupyter Notebook." For using that, the OP wants to put the styler invocation on the last line of a cell. And, importantly, in Jupyter, you probably wouldn't really ever use print(df), you'd use display(df).

Any IDE can do it by default or with extensions, eg. VS Code, PyCharm, DataSpell...
With VSC you can use default Data Viever other extensions eg. Data Wrangler (that uses venv with pandas)

